# Looping through data until date is today

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Student can go to classes and how many hours he spent on class recorded in Student_Hours table. Student is considered exited from school if he/she doesn’t have any hours recorded in 100 days. Need to go through ‘Student_Hours’ table and find all the times he exited, in below example, student 1 has first contact hours on 1/1/2017 and last contact hours on 5/1/2017 and there are no contact hours within 100 days from this date and exit date is 8/9/2017 (5/1/17 + 100).

Need to add 100 days to first contact hour date, find are there any hours between this date range, if so take last contact hours date add 100 days to this date and look for hours in this date range, if nothing found then add 100 days to last contact hours date and make it an exit date.

Student

```
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  3 | c    |
|  4 | d    |
|  5 | e    |
+----+------+
```

Class

```
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
| 10 | c10  |
| 20 | c20  |
| 30 | c30  |
+----+------+
```

Student_Hours

```
+------------+----------+------------+-------+
| Student_Id | Class_Id | Hours_Date | Hours |
+------------+----------+------------+-------+
|          1 |       10 | 1/1/2017   |     2 |
|          1 |       10 | 3/1/2017   |     5 |
|          1 |       10 | 5/1/2017   |     6 |
|          1 |       20 | 12/1/2017  |     9 |
|          2 |       10 | 1/1/2017   |     1 |
|          2 |       10 | 1/31/2017  |     2 |
|          2 |       10 | 2/31/2017  |     2 |
|          2 |       10 | 7/5/2017   |     2 |
|          2 |       10 | 11/1/2017  |     4 |
|          2 |       10 | 3/1/2018   |     4 |
+------------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Output data

```
+------------+-----------------------+------------+
| Student_Id | Last Contact Hrs Date | Exit Date  |
+------------+-----------------------+------------+
|          1 | 5/1/2017              | 8/9/2017   |
|          2 | 7/5/2017              | 10/31/2017 |
|          2 | 11/1/2017             | 2/9/2018   |
+------------+-----------------------+------------+
```

TIA

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

See this as a working model at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/37e47/2) (MS SQL Server 2017 Schema)

```
CREATE TABLE Student  
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(100))
;

INSERT INTO Student  
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b'),
    (3, 'c'),
    (4, 'd'),
    (5, 'e')
;

CREATE TABLE Class   
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Class   
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (10, 'c10'),
    (20, 'c20'),
    (30, 'c30')
;

CREATE TABLE Student_Hours   
    ([Student_Id] int, [Class_Id] int, [Hours_Date] datetime, [Hours] int)
;

INSERT INTO Student_Hours   
    ([Student_Id], [Class_Id], [Hours_Date], [Hours])
VALUES
    (1, 10, '2017-01-01 11:00:00', 2),
    (1, 10, '2017-03-01 11:00:00', 5),
    (1, 10, '2017-05-01 10:00:00', 6),
    (1, 20, '2017-12-01 11:00:00', 9),
    (2, 10, '2017-01-01 11:00:00', 1),
    (2, 10, '2017-01-31 11:00:00', 2),
    (2, 10, '2017-03-03 11:00:00', 2),
    (2, 10, '2017-07-05 10:00:00', 2),
    (2, 10, '2017-11-01 11:00:00', 4),
    (2, 10, '2018-03-01 11:00:00', 4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
       s.name AS student_name
     , sh.class_name
     , sh.mindate
     , max(case when sh.in_100days = 1 then hours_date end) latest_in100days
from student s
left join (
    select
           student_id
         , c.name as class_name
         , min(hours_date) over(partition by student_id, class_id) AS mindate
         , hours_date
         , case when hours_date <= dateadd(dd,100,min(hours_date) over(partition by student_id, class_id)) then 1 else 0 end AS in_100days
    from student_hours sh
    inner join class c on sh.class_id = c.id
    ) sh on s.id = sh.student_id
group by
       s.name
     , sh.class_name
     , sh.mindate
order by
       s.name
     , sh.class_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/37e47/2/0)**:

```
| student_name | class_name |              mindate |     latest_in100days |
|--------------|------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|            a |        c10 | 2017-01-01T11:00:00Z | 2017-03-01T11:00:00Z |
|            a |        c20 | 2017-12-01T11:00:00Z | 2017-12-01T11:00:00Z |
|            b |        c10 | 2017-01-01T11:00:00Z | 2017-03-03T11:00:00Z |
|            c |     (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|            d |     (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|            e |     (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
```